# Shiro: code-duplication in datasource configuration

Tags: configuration, datasource, code-duplication, shiro

I use shiro to implement authentication for my CXF web service. I am using a jdbc-Realm and configured it with the help of an ini-file (attached below). The authentication data is persisted in the same database like the other data I need, but for the rest of the system I use a properties-file (can be found below, too) to provide the connection-information.

Now obviously the data for the datasource in both cases is the same, but I do not seem to find a way to resolve this code duplication. Does anybody more experienced with the development of webapplications have a solution? I could change both, the config of shiro and of the rest of the system, if it would help.

Thanks in advance, 
zakum

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?;

ds = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
ds.user = postgres
ds.password = password
ds.databaseName = servicedb
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.portNumber = 5432

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

service.properties:

```
db. It looks like:
db.name = servicedb
db.user = postgres
db.password = password
db.url = //localhost:5432/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a container like Spring to configure Shiro and your JDBC connections.  Then you can pass the dataSource as a reference into the JDBCRealm.

```
<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="com.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource>
  <property name="driverClassName" value"class for driver"/>
  ... more setup for the data source ...
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"/>
  <property name="permissionsLookupEnabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="authenticationQuery" value="SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am afraid I won't be able to verify your answer, because I don't work on this project anymore. I'll contact my successor to see whether he is interested in trying that out, and report back. That being said, I don't like the idea of using spring, because we'd have to introduce it specifically for this purpose, which seems to be a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could automatically replace tokens during your build process using Ant or Maven (among others).
Here's an example using Ant:

```
<copy file="shiro.template.ini" tofile="shiro.ini" overwrite="true" />
<replace file="shiro.ini" token="@DB_NAME@" value="servicedb"/>
```

In the *.template.* files you'd use tokens:

```
ds.databaseName = @DB_NAME@
```

which would get replaced with the real values during the build process:

```
ds.dataBaseName = servicedb
```

(and it would obviously be better to specify the tokens/values in a configuration file and apply the replacements to a list of files using globbing patterns)

**Ant**: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html
**Maven**: https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I had a similar query and I solved it the following way. Hope it will be helpful to others.

Shiro ini can be used to configure any class. For data source, I have written my application specific class as this.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class MyConfig
{
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(Object ds)
    {
        dataSource = (DataSource)ds;
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource() // your application will use this method to get data source.
    {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Now in the ini file, I passed the same datasource reference to both, the jdbc realm and my class.

```
myConfig = my.package.MyConfig
myConfig.dataSource = $ds
```